# how to implement an idl-to-java compiler

Tags: java, compiler-construction, corba, idl

I need to implement an idl-to-java compiler. In fact, it's not idl-to-java. Interface definition language is extended. So I need to implement a compiler which can generates java source file. I know nothing about corba and I feel hard to start. Do you think it's possible for me to finish this work in half a year? and if so, what should I do. ps: please forgive my English.

Comment: Why do you need to implement an idl-to-java compiler? Why not use one of the existing open source CORBA stacks and IDL compilers out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know anything about parsers and parser generators it's going to be a tough job, but I think that half a year should be plenty if you don't start from scratch.

I suggest that you use [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org:8080/), which happens to have an [IDL parser implementation](http://www.antlr.org:8080/grammar/IDL) among its contributed examples. This is probably for an older version of Antlr, but it's definitely a good starting point. Be sure to get hold of the [Antlr book](http://pragprog.com/book/tpantlr/the-definitive-antlr-reference), you're going to need it!

For the code generation part you could use [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/), a template engine written by Antlr's author, Terence Parr, exactly for this purpose.

If you really have to implement a whole ORB you might as well check out how others did it, e.g. [here](http://www.jacorb.org/).

Comment: IDL is a sort of simplified C++, so that shouldn't pose much of a problem. The point however is what your generated code should do. Are you expected to implement a full CORBA object broker? That would be tough indeed.

Comment: I know there is a compiler in jdk called idlj. I compile a simple idl program with it and it generates a lot of java files, something like helper , holder, POA, Stub stuff. This really confused me. It is a problem to me how to generate these extra files.

Comment: @Sky Shaw: I updated my answer to include advice on code generation.

Comment: @Sky Shaw - all that stuff is going to confuse you if you don't know CORBA. Learn CORBA, and more precisely, learn the OMG-specified IDL to Java mappings. You just don't take the IDL and turn it into java in any we want. There is a precise specification that mandates how to IDL artifacts should map to Java. Furthermore, the IDL compiler will be generating Java artifacts that are specific to the orb in question, so it is not just the IDL compiler in isolation. The IDL compiler is not meant to exist in isolation, but to be part of a CORBA stack (an ORB at a minimum.)

Answer (score 2):

A true IDL-to-java not only spews Java code that maps that stuff back to IDL definitions (strictly adhering to the OMG standards). It also generate Java code that allows your definitions to work with an underlying CORBA stack (not unlike a true compiler generating instructions for a target hardware architecture.)

That is, an IDL compiler

1) takes your IDL definitions and converts them into CORBA-stack, language-specific independent definitions (in your case, in Java).

2) In addition to that, it generates CORBA-stack/vendor specific code as well.

If all you need is something that does #1, then it's not an IDL-to-Java compiler (not in the true sense of the word). But we can call it that for the sake of simplicity.

So you have two possible routes here:

1) Look at the source code of IDL compilers from existing CORBA stacks that are Java based (OpenOrb or JacOrb), or

2) Look at the OMG's specs that tell you how to map from IDL to your language of choice: http://www.omg.org/technology/documents/idl2x_spec_catalog.htm

This is all assuming you know about compiler theory and implementation. Otherwise, if this is an experiment for learning, great! But if this is part of work with a deadline, this could be an unrealistic task.

Either way, good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can use idl4emf:

http://code.google.com/p/idl4emf/

This project is composed by an IDL grammar implementation in Xtext and an IDL metamodel implementation in Ecore.

This project also includes a code generator project from IDL files. You can implement your own generator  from IDL files just writing Xpand templates in Eclipse EMF.

I've used this project as part of several generator projects successfully.